# Как найти шансы на выпадение числе, зная их среднее арифметическое

Tags: математика, excel, теория-вероятностей

Даны 4 числа, условный лутбокс. В нем 4 награды, каждая имеет свою цену. Шанс выпадения самой крутой награды = 2% (и у нее самая большая стоимость). Стоимость наград известна.

Среднее арифметическое выпавшей награды должно быть равно N (тоже известно).

Как распределить шансы выпадения других трех наград?

Интересует именно метод нахождения. Чтобы он работал с разными переменными

Подумал о том, чтобы отталкиваться от среднего арифметического, но еще не нашел как грамотно соотнести его с ценами остальных предметов, чтобы, с учетом последнего (с шансом выпадения 2%) - все грамотно считалось

Comment: Под "среднем арифметическим выпавшей награды" подразумевается, что за открытие X лутбоксов (X->бесконечности) мы получим, в среднем, наград на N (из сундука падает только 1 награда за открытие)

Answer (score 2):

Среднее арифметическое выпавшей награды связано с вероятностями и со стоимостью каждой награды уравнением:

N = c<sub>1</sub>p<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>p<sub>2</sub> + c<sub>3</sub>p<sub>3</sub> + c<sub>4</sub>p<sub>4</sub>,

Причем 0,02 + p<sub>2</sub> + p<sub>3</sub> + p<sub>4</sub> = 1, а также p<sub>2</sub> ≥ 0, p<sub>3</sub> ≥ 0, p<sub>4</sub> ≥ 0.

Значит, вы можете подобрать любые вероятности p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub>, p<sub>4</sub>, удовлетворяющие этим условиям.

Comment: Не любые, а не меньшие нуля, и чтобы их сумма была 98% :)

Comment: @Harry, спасибо за уточнение, добавил!

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить о способе нахождения требуемых вероятностей для выпадения трёх наград для получения заданной средней награды и учитывать тег `Excel`, можно использовать надстройку "Поиск решения".
Целевую функцию задать как `=СУММПРОИЗВ(B3:B6;C3:C6)`, где в столбце `B` будут награды, а в столбце `С` будут вероятности. Далее находим минимум и максимум целевой функции, между которыми можно задавать средние значения награды для нахождения вероятностей. В ограничениях указываем, что сумма всех вероятностей = 100% и ставим галку, что переменные без ограничений - неотрицательные. См. скриншоты.

**Это минимум**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Это максимум**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Это найдено целевое значение средней награды между макс. и мин.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]